# Why is the dot product of two unit vectors equal to zero?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Can someone explain why the scalar product of $\hat{i} \cdot \hat{j}=0$ and the cross product of $\hat{i} \times \hat{j}=\hat{k}.$ Here we define $\hat{i}=(1,0,0), \hat{j}=(0,1,0), \hat{k}=(0,0,1)$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the definitions of "dot/cross" product.

Comment: As usual, the best place to go is the definitions.  First, the definition of $i,j,k$ is that they are the vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ respectively.  Second, the definition of the dot product.  $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot (b_1,b_2,b_3) = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$.  Do you then see why $(1,0,0)\cdot (0,1,0)=0$?  Now... go on to look up the definition of the cross product.  Apply the definition to $i,j,k$ and see the result.  I'll leave the google searching for that last one to you to let you practice your googlefu and not have to rely on asking here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort at all and should be answerable by a simple google search and reading of the definitions.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Can you give an explanation in a geometrical perspective

Comment: @Monsta...welcome to the site....its always a good idea to frame a question in mathjax ; so go for it ....secondly, elaborate the question as much as possible showing neatly as to what all efforts you have put in or stating clearly as to what exactly is unclear.....if it is something related to interpretation or definition then mention what part of definition or interpretation you having trouble with....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots,b_n)$. Then by definition of calar product, we have $$a.b=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3+\cdots+ a_nb_n.$$ In your case,if $n=3$, we have $i=(1,0,0)$ and $j=(0,1,0)$ and thier scalar product is given by
$$i.j=1\cdot 0+0\cdot 1+0\cdot 0=0.$$

For vector product, refer the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the definition of the dot product: $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} = 
(\vec{u}_\hat{i} \times \vec{v}_\hat{i})
+
(\vec{u}_\hat{j} \times \vec{v}_\hat{j})
+
(\vec{u}_\hat{k} \times \vec{v}_\hat{k})
$$

*i.e.:*
$$(2,5,6)\cdot(1,5,6)=(2\times1)+(5\times5)+(6\times6)=2+25+36=63$$

Now, let's see what happens if we use unit vectors:
$$(1, 0)\cdot(0, 1) = (1\times0)+(0\times1) = 0 + 0 = 0$$

---

Another way you can think of the dot product of $\vec{i} \cdot \vec{j}$ to be, *"How much of $\hat{i}$ is being projected onto $\hat{j}$?*

That is, if you took $\hat{i}$ and flattened it onto $\hat{j}$, how much of the length of $\hat{j}$ would be covered by this squashed version of $\hat{i}$? In this case, since they are perpendicular, the piece of $\hat{i}$ projected onto $\hat{j}$ would be zero.

Comment: wonderfully explained in a geometric way. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind explaining for cross product?